# select max value for each ID (including the possibility of multiple max values for one ID!)

Tags: postgresql, max, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table let's say with an ID and a score. I would like to have for each ID the maximum score. But it may happens that I have the same score for one ID and in this case I want to have both the values. So let's say I have a table

```
ID    score
1     10
1     10
2     8
2     6
```

I would like to have as a result

```
ID    score
1     10
1     10
2     8
```

It would be a combination of

```
 SELECT ID, max(score) FROM tbl GROUP BY ID, score ORDER BY ID
```

and

```
select * from tbl where score = (select max (score) from tbl)
```

I tried

```
select * from tbl where score = (select max (score) from tbl GROUP BY ID)
```

But of course it says that I have multiple lines in a subquery. And I want those multiple lines I don't want to limit it to 1.

I tried

```
 SELECT * FROM tbl AS tbl1
 JOIN 
(select * from tbl where score = (select max (score) from tbl)) 
ON tbl1.ID=tbl.ID
```

But it says "subquery in FROM must have an alias" I gave aliases to all subqueries and I still have this error.

Comment: `select * from tbl t where not exists (select * from tbl x where x.id = t.id and x.score > t.score);` voila!

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to use a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html):

```
WITH themaxes AS
(SELECT id, max(score) AS maxscore FROM tbl GROUP BY ID)
SELECT t.* FROM tbl t INNER JOIN themaxes m ON m.id = t.id AND m.maxscore = t.score;
```

another way would be to use a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) (this example uses a subquery with an alias):

```
SELECT id,score FROM 
(SELECT rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY score DESC) AS therank, * FROM tbl) t 
WHERE therank = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
The first solution works perfectly, thank you! Just to let you know,the second  solution is giving only the maximum value for the score (10) repeated but not the association ID 2 score 8.

Comment: Really? Both queries return identical results on my test data!

Comment: @mlinth which is faster?